# Matlab Array Sorting

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I have an array(from excel file) like this;

raw =

```
':Gamer Name'    'mail'                    'true'    'false'    'Date'               
'Haydar'         [                   1]    [2]    [3]    [                   5]
'Çınar'         [                   3]    [4]    [1]    [                   6]
'Ali'            [                   2]    [5]    [2]    [                   3]
' Oyuncu'        [                 NaN]    [0]    [3]    [                 NaN]
' Oyuncu'        [                 NaN]    [0]    [3]    [                 NaN]
' Oyuncu'        [                 NaN]    [0]    [3]    '11-Apr-2017 19:17:10'
' Haydar'        'haydarc'                 [0]    [3]    '11-Apr-2017 19:22:14'
[        NaN]    [                 NaN]    [0]    [3]    '11-Apr-2017 19:24:40'
[        NaN]    [                 NaN]    [3]    [0]    '11-Apr-2017 19:27:45'
' Haydar'        'haydarcinar@yandex…'    [3]    [0]    '11-Apr-2017 20:02:04'
```

I want to sort by 'True'.  How can i do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract out the indices of sorting through [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) based on the third column (i.e. `true`) of your cell array, then rearrange the rows of your cell array based on that. Use the second output of `sort` to help you do this.

However, your first row consists of characters.  What you'll need to do is pull out the first row, sort on the numerics, then reconstruct the sorted cell array putting this first row back:

```
raws = raw(2:end, :);
[~,ind] = sort(cell2mat(raws(:, 3));
raw_sorted = [raw(1,:); raws(ind, :));
```

The function [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) helps convert your column of cells in the `true` column to be a matrix so we can successfully use `sort`.  Once we find the indices of sorting, simply index into your cell array without the first row, but make sure you place the first row back.

Comment: Thank you sir. I have tried to sort for 1 hour now. But I couldn't . I am grateful to you :)

Comment: @haydarçınar no problem at all :) Good luck!

Comment: You can also pack this data into a table instead of a cell array and then just call `sortrows`.

Comment: @CKT Good idea, but I wanted to be as general as possible.  `table` was not introduced until R2013b.